# messages like textbox in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I want to know how can I create a textbox that looks like the one in the messaging app in windows phone (bubble textbox)?

I've been able to create one that looks like it using a regular textbox and a path to create the triangle.

However, I wasn't able to create the same effect when the input is focused (with a border around the entire bubble.)

**Screenshots:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzwV5.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzT3b.png

Comment: Use Expression BLend.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal How can i shape the border?

Comment: Maybe you could try "erasing" that portion of the original border where you'd want the triangle to stick out? You could bind the color of that segment to the background fill of the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You have `ChatBubble` and `ChatBubbleTextBox` controls available in the [Coding4Fun toolkit](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/).

If they don't fit exactly to what you want, you can try by aplying changes over their templates.

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of the list view which contains the messages aligned, See VerticalContentAlignment set it to bottom.
[image: VerticalContentAlignment for list box]